# Validate that a web application has used a specific hash function for its certificate

Tags: security

What is the process for verifying the hash function that was used to create a web applications certificate?  I ask because there apparently has been some issue with the MD5 hash function wherein someone malicious can fake a certificate.

Comment: Lots of background info here http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 3 has all MD5 encryption disabled by default except for RC4/128 (filter `about:config` by md5)

Lots more info here: [The new MD5/SSL exploit is NOT the end of civilization as we know it](http://blogs.techrepublic.com/security/?p=724)